# Why does this method cause an Infinite Recursive call?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, avl-tree, recursive-datastructures

I'm struggling to understand why this class is not functioning. It was part of an assignment for a course on Data Structures(EDIT: The deadline for the assignment has passed, I just want to figure it out...). The node is part of an AVL tree built upon a BST and the way I chose to implement it is by creating methods within my Node class to find the Balance factor and height.

The class is structured as follows:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

public T data;
public Node left;
public Node right;

public Node(T IN) {
    data = IN;
}

public Node(T IN, Node L, Node R) {
    this(IN);
    left = L;
    right = R;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return data.toString();
}

@Override
public Node clone() {
    return new Node(this.data) ;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return getHeight(this) ;
}

public int getBF() {

        //Calculate BF
        int balanceFactor = 0;
        if (right != null && left != null)
            balanceFactor = getHeight(right) - getHeight(left);
        else if (left != null) {
            balanceFactor = 0 - getHeight(left) ;
        }
        else if (right != null) {
            balanceFactor = getHeight(right) ;
        }
        else
            balanceFactor = 0 ;
        return balanceFactor ;
}

private int getHeight(Node p) {
    if (p.left == null && p.right == null ) {
        return 0 ;
    }
    else if (p.left != null && p.right != null) {
        return 1 + max(p.left.getHeight(), p.right.getHeight());
    }
    else if (p.left != null) {
        return 1 + p.left.getHeight() ;
    }
    else if (p.right != null) {
        return 1 + p.right.getHeight() ;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

private int max(int x, int y) {
    if (x >= y) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return y;
    }
}
```

}

and the function calling the method is:

```
@Override
public boolean insert(T el) {
    boolean test = super.insert(el) ;
    if (test) {
        return checkBalance(root) ;
    }
    else
        return false ;
}
```

and the exception I recieve is a repetition of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Node.getHeight(Node.java:54)
at Node.getHeight(Node.java:33)
at Node.getHeight(Node.java:58)
```

Comment: By the way, shouldn't the base case return 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Be sure left and right reference null in the default and in the "int Node(T IN)" constructors    :)

Comment: Did you check if you have a circle in your tree? This may cause the error...

Comment: @Drewen: why shouldn't they be?

Comment: Well, in C++ is a "must" practice, but I just saw in Java it isn't  :)

Comment: @ppeterka Oops, you are right it should :P

Comment: @Drewen It would be better practice, but Java sometimes makes me lazy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that either your tree is deformed or really big. There seems to be no problems with the code.

If your tree is deformed in such a way that you have a `Node` inserted twice in the same tree then this code will break.

**Added** - You are eating a little more stack than you need - replacing `p.left.getHeight()` with `getHeight(p.left)` etc. would avoid one stack push per recursion. If your issue is merely *big tree* then this might scrape you through but this would only postpone the problem.

Comment: If I test the getHeight() and getBF() methods with a simple binary tree it seems to work, I'll take a look at my AVL tree to see if it is broken, thanks.

Comment: I fixed it!

The problem was in my AVL-tree's checkBalance() method, I had simply switched my rotations around and the problem existed because of the broken tree, so thank you to @OldCurmudgeon for making me look at my Data structure!

Answer (score 2):

From looking at both getHeight methods, it seems like you don't have a tree but a cyclic graph. You should start testing with a tree consisting of only the root and then add nodes until you observe the infinite recursion. You probably have an error in the function that rebalances the tree.

EDIT: And you should make the attributes (at least left and right) private.

Comment: "*From looking at both getHeight methods, it seems like you don't have a tree but a cyclic graph*" - how did you get to this conclusion?

Comment: Because if it's a noncyclic graph the methods as they are won't lead to infinite recursion.